# How to use Kafka Schema Registry for create a users table in KSQL?

Tags: apache-kafka, jsonschema, confluent-schema-registry, ksqldb

I have kafka topics with JSON data. There is a topic called users which capture data changes from mysql table.

How to use confluent schema registry to create a users table in ksql with a primary key user_id which will to be used with other tables with joins?

Current Kafka user topic has  data like this:

```
 {"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"id"}],"optional":false,"name":"myserver.db.users.Key"},"payload":
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, your mysql data arrived from Kafka Connect JSONConverter, and has no Registry information.

If so, you'd start there, by editing the converter (JSON Schema, Protobuf or Avro, instead), rather than ksqlDB, since parsing JSON has no integration with the Registry.

Then you'd setup ksqlDB stream/table with the appropriate type, following the docs. Otherwise, you can still parse the plain JSON text, but if you want any Registry schemas, you'll need to convert into one of the formats that the Registry supports (thus, duplicating your kafka topic).

However, none of that is required to join data in ksqlDB

Comment: I'm going to use schema registry with java a java client. Do you know what are the java repositories available to create a schema registry ? @OneCricketeer

Comment: Did you search for it? https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-clients/java/current/overview.html + https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/serdes-json.html#using-schema-annotation-on-the-java-object

Comment: I was looking for implement confluent kafka community edition.I think the schema registry mentioned by you is supports only for confluent kafka enterprise edition

Comment: That is not true. Confluent Schema Registry is open source, and part of community edition